# Multiple checks in beforeShowDay - jQueryUI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

In short, I want the datepicker to first disable all sundays - I use this code:

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: function(day) {
       var day = day.getDay();
       if (day == 0) {
         return [false, "busy"]
       } else {
         return [true, "free"]
       }
     }
});
```

It works. But then I also want to disable specific dates within a range that is stored in an array:

```
jQuery("#datepicker").datepicker({ 
    beforeShowDay: function (date) {    
        var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [dateRange.indexOf(dateString) == -1];
    }
});
```

This also works and disables the days that I want.

**Problem:** Both codes works seperately - how  can I combine them so both sundays are disabled and my custom dates from the array?

Comment: What about use the same nameparameter for both functions ? have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help you. Try following code:

```
$(function(){  
   $('#thedate').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date) {
         var dateString = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
         var day = date.getDay();
         if (day == 0 || dateRange.indexOf(dateString) != -1) {
                return [false, "busy"]
         } else {
                return [true, "free"]
         }
     }
  });   
});
```

Here is working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ionutmihai1995/8w8v9/2264/).

Comment: Awesome. This makes so much sense, I just couldn't stable it together. Thank you sir!